# IndexError: list out of range in a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyautogui

So I was editing my big automatisation script, when I needed to change place in the code for the following code. After placing the code in the upper position in the script I suddenly started getting the following error:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\clicker.py", line 198, in <module>
    while a[i] != None:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried checking the indexes, but they appear to be fine. I have no clue how to debug this further.. What is weird the error is shown at the end of while loop (I know how to fix it if it gets shown at the start only). That means every detected coordinate in the list gets executed and it fails at the very end when no more coordinates exist. My code is:

```
 # convert broken xls to working xlsx
    pyautogui.click(x=75, y=746)
    sleep(1)
    pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/User/Documents/Clicker/downloads.png'))
    sleep(3)
    a = list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('C:/Users/User/Documents/Clicker/excel.png'))
    i=0
    while a[i] != None:
        x, y = pyautogui.center(a[i])
        pyautogui.click(x, y, clicks=2)
        sleep(4)
        pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/User/Documents/Clicker/yes.png'))
        sleep(2.5)
        try:
            pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/User/Documents/Clicker/editing.png'))
        except TypeError:
            print("No need to press editing mode")
        # click file
        pyautogui.click(x=29, y=50)
        sleep(1)
        # click save as
        pyautogui.click(x=50, y=312)
        sleep(1)
        # click on drop down menu
        pyautogui.click(x=814, y=177)
        sleep(2)
        # select .xlsx
        pyautogui.click(x=814, y=200)
        sleep(1)
        # click save
        pyautogui.click(x=920, y=170)
        sleep(2)
        # close excel
        pyautogui.click(x=997, y=14)
        sleep(2)
        i+=1
    #-----EXCEL------------
```

Comment: If you have a while loop and at each item you increment the index, don't you see that at some point you will reach an index that doesn't exist? Also, why don't you use a for loop with the correct number of elements?

Comment: Why did the code work before then? I don't use a for loop because I don't know how many excel files (in this case) there are.

Comment: Please explain where you're confused.  You've described the situation quite accurately: you iterated through the list until you ran out of legal indices, and then tried to go one step further.  You're out of range.

Comment: @Prune I think I got what is wrong, but I don't get how should I fix it when I don't know the amount of files without a while loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, I would highly recommend updating your sleep() methods to use waiting methods that know if your clicks have loaded. In different service zones and wifi zones, your network is not always super fast or slow and so implicitly waiting for something to load will ensure you don't move on before something hasn't finished executing.

Secondly, Why not just use a for loop? This way you do not need to track indices.

```
pyautogui.click(x=75, y=746)
sleep(1)
pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/User/Documents/Clicker/downloads.png'))
sleep(3)
a = list(pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('C:/Users/User/Documents/Clicker/excel.png'))
for item in a:
    x, y = pyautogui.center(item)
    pyautogui.click(x, y, clicks=2)
    sleep(4)
    pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/User/Documents/Clicker/yes.png'))
    sleep(2.5)
    try:
        pyautogui.click(pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('C:/Users/User/Documents/Clicker/editing.png'))
    except TypeError:
        print("No need to press editing mode")
    # click file
    pyautogui.click(x=29, y=50)
    sleep(1)
    # click save as
    pyautogui.click(x=50, y=312)
    sleep(1)
    # click on drop down menu
    pyautogui.click(x=814, y=177)
    sleep(2)
    # select .xlsx
    pyautogui.click(x=814, y=200)
    sleep(1)
    # click save
    pyautogui.click(x=920, y=170)
    sleep(2)
    # close excel
    pyautogui.click(x=997, y=14)
    sleep(2)
#-----EXCEL------------
```

Comment: Can you edit your answer to include waiting methods?

Comment: you could also use pyautogui's builtin waiting:```pyautogui.PAUSE = int()``` to auto set the sleep time after every movement, and it also happen after complete the movement,which will make sure click is loaded

Answer (score 3):

```
while a[i] != None:
    x, y = pyautogui.center(a[i])
```

Instead, use

```
for i in range(len(a)):
    x, y = pyautogui.center(a[i])
```

Or, since you don't use `i` for anything else,

```
for item in a:
    x, y = pyautogui.center(item)
```

Please review your materials on loops.  You should have picked up these techniques from there.